# How to change group to files stored on an NTFS partition from ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, django

I'm working on a django app in ubuntu 9.10, and I have the files stored on an NTFS partition (becaus I have double boot and, sadly, still have to do some stuff with windows). Testing it with the django toy server was doing fine, but when I tried to test it with apache, I found a problem: I tried to change the group of the files to www-data, but the changes didn't seem to take effect!
Does it mean that I'll have to copy my *whole* project to an ext[34] partition if I want to use apache? That doesn't sound so good...
Is there a way to do it, to use chgrp or any other command and let www-data execute my python modules stored in the NTFS partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NTFS does not support *nix permissions. What you are trying to do will not work. You can mount the entire NTFS volume as a given user and group via mount options.

Comment: I thought so. Thanks nevertheless. Since it's only for a local network test, I just changed the envvars of apache so it uses the group "root"  instead of "www-data". It works, it could be dangerous, I know, but its super temporary.